# How do I determine if a graph has a cycle in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, graph, cycle

So what I'm trying to do is implement Kruskal's algorithm from a 2d array (called G) like this:

```
0  0  0  0  0  12 13 0 
0  0  6  0  0  0  0  3 
0  6  0  4  0  0  0  5
0  0  4  0  10 0  0  7
0  0  0  10 0  11 8  9
12 0  0  0  11 0  1  0 
13 0  0  0  8  1  0  2
0  3  5  7  9  0  2  0
```

The 0's mean no edge is connecting those two vertices and a value means an edge is connecting two vertices where the value represents the edge's weight and the row and column is the two vertices it's connecting. So 12 would be connecting 0 and 5. So what I decided to do is find the smallest element in the array and then add that to another 2d array (H) that's the same size as G but all the values are 0. Then I check and see if adding that edge forms a cycle and if it does then I remove the edge from H and keep going until every row is filled. Here's what I did:

```
        int numVerts = G.length;

        int [][] H = new int[numVerts][numVerts];
        int minWeight;
        int k = 0;
        int l = 0;
        int boolcount = 0;
        boolean [] R = new boolean[G.length];
        Arrays.fill(R, false);

        while (boolcount != numVerts){
            for (int i = 0; i < numVerts; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < numVerts; j++){
                    if ((G[i][j] != 0) && (G[i][j] < minWeight)){
                        minWeight = G[i][j];
                        k = i;
                        l = j;
                    }
                }
            }
            H[k][l] = minWeight;
            H[l][k] = minWeight;
            G[k][l] = 0;
            G[l][k] = 0;
            if (/*it forms a cycle*/){
            H[k][l] = 0;
            H[l][k] = 0;
            } else {
                //keep the edge
            }
```

So the only thing I need to figure out now is how do I check if an edge forms a cycle with any other edge in H. Based on how the arrays are represented in the 2d array, I could I figure out if the edges form cycles? One way I was thinking is using union-find to say if the newly added edge is in the union as the other edges then don't add it because it creates a cycle but I'm having trouble implementing that.

P.S: I also didn't post the code for when I decide to keep the edge but basically that's where I update the boolcount for when I determine when to stop traversing.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a starting vertex. Traverse the graph breadth first while negating the edge weights as you pass them. If you come across a an edge whose weight is <0, then you have a cyclic graph.

Comment: But how do I implement breadth first search in a 2d array? I've only seen that get implemented via things like a linked list.

Comment: Your 2d array is a representation of a graph. The name of that data structure is "adjacency matrix". You can find plenty of information on how to perform breadth first searching on an adjacency matrices on google... this is a well known problem and the algorithmic solutions are also well known. I could repeat it in my answer but at what cost...

Comment: Ok one last question. you told me to negate the edge weights as I pass them but then after I finish the search am I supposed to put all those edges weights to positive again because I will be performing this search multiple times for each edge I add.

Comment: Negating them is for memory efficiency; assuming that none of the edges hold a negative weight in the first place. You can either negate them all again after the first run or use a boolean flag to indicate whether they were negated towards negativity or positivity the last time your algorithm ran... there are many ways to solve this depending on your situation.

Comment: I'm still having trouble implementing this. Would I need to use a queue to implement this?